Подключение нескольких аккаунтов телеграм к одному api
Возникла необходимость использовать одновременно множество (предположим, что 10) аккаунтов телеграм, всвязи с этим возник вопрос: можно ли их всех поместить под один ключ api? То бишь для всех аккаунтов использовать один и тот же api_id и api_hash. И если все же есть ограничение, то каково оно?
Использую pyrogram 2.0.106.
